# Yum install not writing anything to my /etc/ (ELK Stack)

Tags: elasticsearch, yum, elastic-stack

I'm running Centos 6  and whenever I run `sudo yum -y install elasticsearch-1.1.1'` I get the following:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Repository base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository updates is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package matching elasticsearch-1.1.1-1.noarch already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

Whenever I try to modify the yaml file located at /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml this directory does not exist. Does this mean my yum is not writing the files to the directory?

Answer (score 0):

I used:

rpm -e --nodeps `yum list installed | grep elasticsearch.noarch | awk '{ print $1 }'